# Comma after "You know what" phrase

Tags: commas

We need to put a commas after the "you know" sentence

> You know, I need to go home.

But is it right to put it after almost the same sentence "You know what"?

> You know what, he often says this word.

Comment: It is technically  a question (Do you know what thought has just occurred to me?), so I would use a question mark and then start a new sentence.

Comment: @KateBunting I see.. In your case it's a question. But in my situation I have affirmative sentence.

Comment: @АртурГудиев: *you know what?* is an idiom meaning *do you know this?*. It needs a question mark. *You know what? I'm hungry; let's go to the cafe.*

Comment: It may feel like an affirmative, but if you are using "You know what" to introduce a new idea, it's technically a question. Oxford Dictionaries say _Used to indicate that one is going to say something interesting or surprising.
"You know what? I believed her"_

Comment: @KateBunting Ok, thanks! Now I understand

Comment: Wiktionary is happy to give an example without the question mark where the pragmatic marker 'you know what' is obviously a paraphrase of 'would you believe it', rhetorical. [Longmans](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/would-you-believe-it) has an exclamation mark in place of the question mark in 'Would you believe it!' But the prescriptivist ... descriptivist balance here is probably still in favour of question marks with interrogative forms (though in favour of question marks with declarative questions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a Russian-speaker, these two usages remind me of the Russian phrases "Знаешь, а..." and "Знаешь что?". However, I feel like their usage varies with the language.

In English, you can only use "you know what?" *as a question*, typically to show that you've come to some conclusion, made a decision or simply agree with someone (e.g. "You know what? That's not a bad idea!" in the sense that "On second thought, I like that idea too"). However, it can also show that you're fed up ("You know what? I can't take it anymore, I'm out).

You can use "you know" in an affirmative sentence to convey agreement ("You know, that's not a bad idea!"), to seek understanding or sympathy ("I just understood that I couldn't stay there anymore, you know?"), or to make a point ("You know, I don't have time for this").

But, in both languages, there's an interrogative version, and an affirmative version.

Comment: Since Longman's licenses 'Would you believe it!' and Wiktionary gives an example (from a CNN transcript) of  'You know what, ...' this comes across as mere opinion. Supporting evidence is required.